# Log middleware email error report

Tags: python, django, logging, django-middleware

Has some middleware to intercept Email sending by error report?

I need to hide some values in log, Im using 'processExceptionMiddleware', but when I have some import error, this middleware do not intercept and some values that I would like to hide is showing in log.

PS: Django 1.3

Comment: How is you `logging` configured and show us an example of failing code.

Comment: I set debug=False and set my email to managers, Im forcing a wrong import just to see what will log, I need a midleware to intercept it before send email